# How to deal with a Wife asking for mehar after she has forgiven it?

Tags: talaq

A nikaah took place in which half of the mehar was paid and half was decided to be paid later.

However after a year the wife said to the husband that she forgives the remaining portion of mehar and she doesn't want it. After 3 years divorce took place between this couple and the husband gave her talaaq.

Now after 6 months the wife is asking for the rest of her mehar, insistently saying that she wants it as she needs it. The husband, however says this mehar is not due on him now because she had already forgiven him the remaining portion of mehar.

How should this matter be resolved?

Answer (score 2):

<sup>**Apparently you are asking for fatwa but *[this is not a fatwa site](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)* . But let me [give an answer from an Islamic point of view](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/907/is-not-to-get-answers-of-deen-on-this-website/908#908).**</sup>

---

Allah says in [4:4](http://quran.com/4/4) :

> And give the women [upon marriage] their [bridal] gifts graciously. But if they give up willingly to you anything of it, **then take it in satisfaction and ease**.

- So the husband is not required to give the half of the dowry (mahr).
- But the wife is entitled to the maintenance that was spent **during the ‘iddah**, based on verse [65:1](http://quran.com/65/1). (fatwa [source](http://islamqa.info/en/126281))

As the wife says that *she needs it*, this falls under *maintenance*, and the husband is required to compensate for the expenditure during iddah, which is [three periods](http://quran.com/2/228), be it more than *the half of the mahr* or less.

---

<sup>This is a conclusion of mine. Please refer to the local Imam for proper judgement</sup>